# How to define a Path for Ruby on Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path

Hello,

I installed Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails (rubygems-1.8.24) successfully on
Windows 7.

After creating a project folder on C: drive like this:

```
c:\rails-projects>
```

and after trying to create a new project like this:

```
rails quizzes-on-rails
```

I get a long menu list about Path.. Now I guess I have to create a
Path, but don't how. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you done `rails new quizzes-on-rails`? That is the command that actually creates the application for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command, instead, to create a new rails project with the name `quizzes-on-rails`:

```
rails new quizzes-on-rails
```